# How to disable printing request information while using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm trying to test a simple search method in twitter4j. My code is

```
public void searchTweets(Query searchQuery) {
    QueryResult queryResult = null;

    try {
        queryResult = twitter.search(searchQuery);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        log.error("Unable to search query = {}", searchQuery, e);
    }
}
```

When i test this above code, i'm getting the following output. How should I disable this output which contains request information?

```
- Request:
- GET http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Sports&since_id=111374710708768768

- OAuth base string: GET&http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.twitter.com%2Fsearch.json&oauth_con
sumer_key%3DABk1pJ6bd5LWcf1lsIa9g%26oauth_nonce%3D914173077%26oauth_signature_me
thod%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1315388678%26oauth_token%3D73081379-KQOkj6E
g4uBdUXSzlpvbtdb5OWOLXD3mxVo9nrdRV%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26q%3DSports%26since_id
%3D111374710708768768
- OAuth signature: oUszlR4fGxq8JiqXNFf+t6SgXdA=
- Authorization: ***************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
*************************************************
- X-Twitter-Client-URL: http://twitter4j.org/en/twitter4j-2.2.5-SNAPSHOT(build:
5f9c44cd0e0c1972f8d17653a226b9b6a3392ac2).xml
- X-Twitter-Client: Twitter4J
- Accept-Encoding: gzip
- User-Agent: twitter4j http://twitter4j.org/ /2.2.5-SNAPSHOT(build: 5f9c44cd0e0
c1972f8d17653a226b9b6a3392ac2)
- X-Twitter-Client-Version: 2.2.5-SNAPSHOT(build: 5f9c44cd0e0c1972f8d17653a226b9
b6a3392ac2)
- Response:
- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- Age: 0
- Content-Length: 1107
- Expires: Wed, 07 Sep 2011 09:51:30 GMT
- Connection: close
- Server: hi
- Cache-Control: max-age=15, must-revalidate, max-age=300
- X-Varnish: 513089989
- Vary: Accept-Encoding
- Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2011 09:46:30 GMT
- Content-Encoding: gzip
- Via: 1.1 varnish
- Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

- text='Montague Action Cricket: Titans 8 be at Forfeit +10 (10 - 1) http://t.co/2RbMzpK'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to log4j.properties: `log4j.logger.twitter4j.internal.http=warn`

Comment: Hi Bozho!! after adding the the above line.. am getting the same request information. We are using twitter4j 4.0.2 version. How to disable the request information?? kindly let me know...

Comment: check if the package structure hasn't changed.